# opening folder browser dialog on button click c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

im trying to trigger a folder browser dialog with a button in c#
ive tried

```
     private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     DialogResult auswahl2 = folderBrowserDialog2.ShowDialog();
     if (auswahl2 == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         TextBox5.Text = folderBrowserDialog2.SelectedPath;
     }
 }
```

but neither debug nor release will open one on button click.
What am i missing ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please add break point on Button2_Click method and check if debugger comes at this point. if not so follow the answer of @Noob002.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your form, and double-click the button in question, see if it pointed to the above function, or a new event function is created.

If it was the second, copy everything above to the new function and run the program again, everything should be fine after that.

If you want to do it manually, go to `YourForm.Designer.cs`, and add `this.Button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button2_Click);` under `InitializeComponent()`.

Or go to the code of your form, select `InitializeComponent` under the constructor, and press `F12`, and it will bring you to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly but check if `Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` event is plugged.

Mehdi

Comment: What do you mean by, if it is plugged, plugged where?

Comment: To use the events, it must be connected to the method. You can try, after InitializeComponent() method try this line : this.Button2.Click += Button2_Click;

Comment: i had to reintialize it